# What is the complete list of comic book references in Deadpool (2016) movie?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

I want to know the entire list of references to the comics in the Deadpool movie. I'm not asking for other things, just the comic book references.

What is the complete list of comic book references in Deadpool (2016) movie?

Comment: Similar question over at Movies & TV. http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/48786

Comment: @Ghostship I'm asking for the comic book references only. Please add more if you know any.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- "Rob L." being shown on a coffee cup. A reference to one of Deadpool’s creators, Rob Liefeld. He and Fabian Nicieza worked on New Mutants #98 back in 1991. This is not the only Liefeld reference in the movie. During the fight scene on the freeway, there are signs for exits named after Liefeld and Nicieza.
  [image]
- The obvious Green Lantern reference.
  [image]
- Wade has an action figure of Deadpool from X-Men Origins: Wolverine.
- Ajax suggests sewing Wade's mouth shut. Wade tells him that it's a bad idea. Just like Deadpool's mouthless depiction in X-Men Origins: Wolverine was.
- Deadpool has a white costume at the beginning. This might be a reference to his X-Force costume.
- Deadpool says he looks like he was bitten by a radioactive shar-pei. This must be a reference to Spider-Man. But there is also a comic version of this.
  [image]
- Deadpool refers to himself as being from Regina, Saskatchewan. Nationality topic bounces back and forth in the comics depending on the writer. But the movie version of Deadpool ended the discussion by calling it Canada. Just like Ryan Reynolds being Canadian. And Wolverine.
- Freddy Krueger thing. It's mentioned a few times in the comics. Most notably by Kate Bishop Hawkeye who thought Wade's skin was a Halloween costume.
- By the end of the movie, Wade gets a knife to the skull. And sees cartoon characters around Vanessa. Ever since Daniel Way took over writing Deadpool (starting with Wolverine Origins #21), he started a regular gag where Deadpool would see the world differently like that. It's been referred to as Pool-o-Vision.
- Cable/Deadpool #13, Deadpool orders chimichangas at restaurants. Just because he loves saying the word.
- Wade’s incident with the pizza guy is heavily based on a scene from Daniel Way’s run with the character. It’s from Deadpool v.4 #10.
- During one scene, Wade is wearing a shirt with Bea Arthur on it. In a running gag that started in Cable/Deadpool #1, Deadpool considered Bea Arthur to be the sexiest woman in show business.
- Vanessa is in the comics.
  [image]
- Weasel is in the comics.
  [image]
- Sister Margaret’s School for Wayward Children, otherwise known as the Hellhouse, is another Joe Kelly creation, appearing in Deadpool v.3 #1.
- The Dead Pool is a thing from the comics, but not at the Hellhouse.
- Ajax, known as Francis, is in the comics.
  [image]
- Colossus, Negasonic Teenage Warhead, Angel Dust and David Cunningham (Worm) are in the comics.
- Deadpool runs into an enemy named Bob that he appears to be old friends with. Ever since debuting in Cable/Deadpool #38, Hydra Bob (or Bob, Agent of Hydra) has been Wade's ever-suffering sidekick.
- Deadpool confirms Cable will be in Deadpool 2. Which is a comic book character.
- The way Deadpool impales the final goon with two katanas and holds him up is very reminiscent of the Adam Kubert cover of Wolverine #88, the first ever meeting between Wolverine and Deadpool.
  [image]

Comment: That double rainbow is wrong in so many levels. The designers should've at least read about the physical process.

Comment: Just so people know, that first poster referencing Green Lantern is not an official poster; it's fan-made. Source: http://m7781.deviantart.com/art/deadpool-x-green-lantern-movie-poster-586877470

Comment: @V2Blast thanks, I forgot giving the source.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández So many levels? I can only think of two (colour inversion and rainbow inversion)… how many more levels is it wrong on?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that's all the possible levels, all of them! Well, in Al honesty it could be intentional... Who knows? :P